# mysql cache question

Tags: mysql, cache

is there a such thing as too much cache? i have a 2GB ram server.

i run 2-3 sites off the following:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable = max_connections=50
log-slow-queries
safe-show-database
skip-networking
skip-name-resolve
set-variable=local-infile=0
local-infile=0
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=32M
table_cache=1024
table_definition_cache=512
max_heap_table_size=512
tmp_table_size=32M
max_heap_table_size=32M
thread_cache=32
key_buffer=64M
read_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
thread_concurrency=4
interactive_timeout=100
wait_timeout=15
connect_timeout=10
long_query_time=1
flush_time=3600

[isamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M
```

.

```
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Storage Engine | Data Size            | Index Size           | Table Size           |
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| InnoDB         |             0.188 MB |             0.250 MB |             0.438 MB |
| MyISAM         |           181.114 MB |            61.270 MB |           242.384 MB |
| Total          |           181.302 MB |            61.520 MB |           242.821 MB |
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

We would need to know how much data there is for MyISAM and InnoDB

Send the result of this query in MB.

SELECT IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size" FROM (SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema') AND engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY engine WITH ROLLUP) B,(SELECT 2 pw) A ORDER BY TSize;

Comment: edit my post above with the details so it shows better